# AdMob Interstitial ad doesn't show after being loaded

Tags: android, android-studio, interstitial, admob

As title says: AdMob Interstitial ad doesn't show after being loaded.
When I open the app it shows the toast "Tap to start" and I tap, and the next activity starts but there is no interstitial ad.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Tap to start");
        }
    });

    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    imageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

    imageview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PlaylistActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                showMessage("Error");
                Log.d("AD", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** Looks like there were no errors, it just takes a very long time to load ads sometimes and sometimes only a few seconds. If you can explain why or how to fix this that would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48021892/4750017

In that first load your Interstitial ad in the launcher activity and then call it from any activity.

Comment: I was looking for something more simple. Like an error, or any other reason why this might not be working.