# Showing interstitial adMob ad when the user exits the app but not by intention

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, mobile-development

Can one show an interstitial ad when the user clicks a button and if the user cancel the ad, he/she would be directed to a website.
So, is the adMob's policy been broken: Interstitial ad should not be shown as the user exits the app.

Clearly here, the user was not intended to actually 'exit' the app, but it's a implicit feature of the app.

I researched a lot but there was no one similar to my problem, I even posted this problem on quora, Google's adMob sdk help forums and even in gmail help forums, but there were no replies.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: I think you tried to ask this, 

*There is a **button** which does **action x**. If the user click the **button**, you first show an Interstitial ad, then do the **action x**.*

am I right?

Comment: Yes you are 100% right, and the action x is: redirect the user to a website in their browser. Which result in exiting the app. So does admob policy get violated here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not much clear to me but what I understand you are asking- Can we show Interstitial Ads on App exit?
No, you cannot show ads on app exit as it violates Admob policy.
For best to implement Admob Interstitial Ads check out my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48021892/4750017

If I am wrong in understanding your question then please provide detail implementation.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, my problem is: my app contains a button which when pressed will redirect the user to a gaming website in their browser by using a intent, but before it happens they will be shown a Interstitial ad. The problem is that the app is being excited by user as they get directed to the website, so does it really breaks admob policy?

Comment: "my app contains a button which when pressed will redirect the user to a gaming website in their browser " Does  it mean site will open in seperate browser app or in webview in same app??

Comment: Site will be opened in the browser app and NOT in a web view. I accomplished it by: intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)) then startActivity(intent)

Comment: Then it is allowed as your activity is not destroyed, it will run in background. When user press back button on browser it will back to your activity and your activity will resume.

Comment: Exactly, you are all right about it. The only problem was what exactly one can mean by the word 'exit'. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In few of my apps i have same flow as yours. In that I have implement to call the interstitial ads then ads listener, if ad is closed or cancel then move to the browser app. I never get any policy violation mail from google. I am using from two years. :) upvote if my answer help you and give you confidence.

Comment: Hi, can you please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172160/can-testing-with-real-admob-ads-after-the-apps-development-results-in-admobs-p

Answer (score 0):

Let me repeat your question in my way

*There is a **button** which does **action x**. If the user click the **button**, first show an Interstitial ad, then do the **action x**.*

If thats your question, the answer will be, if the **action x** doesn't *exit the app*, that means, *if the next thing which will the user experience, after the ad is closed*, then **you can show the ad**.

Like, *if you load the website within your app in a WebView, then you can show the ad.*

But if the next view which the user will see, is not a part of your application, you can't show the ad.

As stated in [Disallowed interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362) article:

> It should be clear to the user which application the ad is associated with or implemented on.

And this type of implementation will lead to a very bad user experience also, so you should avoid it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Comment: If you think this is a good answer, please upvote
. And if you think this is the answer, please accept this as right ans too