# Can testing with real adMob ads after the app's development results in adMob's policy violation?

Tags: android, admob, mobile-development

So my app have been successfully developed and I have had a good experience with the admob test ads. But then just now I tried to view how real ads look like on my app and I started testing with real ads(banners+Interstitial) with keeping in mind: not to click them!
The impressions gets to be 6 and match rate 100%, will this cause me any trouble?? I am new to adMob but I did followed all policies correcty, though I don't know if self impressions are a big deal or not.

Please reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't consider self-impressions. But it takes very serious action like account termination in case of self-clicks or accidental clicks. One two times self click 2-3 months is okay, as Google consider it might be click accidently during development.